# Changing Unity desktop icon text color

Tags: themes

A white desktop wallpaper is not an option in unity desktop currently. Because the text color does not seem changeable. How do we accomplish this?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 2):

The problematic theme is most probably the default radiance theme.
You need to edit

```
 /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css
```

make a backup by copying it to nautilus.old

```
 $ cp /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css  nautilus.old
```

now edit with your favourite text editor (requires SU permissions). 
using nano:

```
$ nano /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css
```

Find the lines:

```
/* desktop mode */
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {
color: @bg_color;
text-shadow: 1px 1px alpha (#000000, 0.8);
}
```

change to

```
/* desktop mode */
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {
color: #000000;
text-shadow: 1px 1px alpha (#ffffff, 0.8);
}
```

to temporarily check if it worked, you may use

```
$ killall nautilus
$ nautilus
```

Logoff and back-in to complete the procedure.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Beats me why this simple tweak can't be a part of Settings->Appearance. How can we ever win over the folks from the walled gardens?